# What is the difference between Evaluation result after creating a model, compared to evaluation using ML.Evaluate in BigQuery ML?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to train a model using BigQuery ML and a bit confused about the functionalities.

When I use the CREATE MODEL function to create the model, it allows me to split the data into training and evaluation. Lets' say I use the AUTO_SPLIT and my rows are between 500 and 50,000, according to the documentation, 20% of the data is used as evaluation in a RANDOM split. Can I assume that the rest 80% will be used for training?

So in a way, by using this CREATE MODEL function, I'm basically training and evaluating at the same time. Is that understanding correct? If yes, then what's the purpose of ML.Evaluate function?

Answer (score 1):

[CREATE MODEL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#data_split_method) statement trains a new model in the specified dataset. One of its options is to set a DATA_SPLIT_METHOD, which splits the input data in two different sets (**training** and **evaluation**) according to the split method. The evaluation data is used to avoid [overfitting](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/glossary/?_ga=2.193511336.401688994.1582531745-1498280486.1572419393&_gac=1.217198242.1582116092.EAIaIQobChMIpMmN29Hd5wIVGp7VCh3lUgcWEAAYASAAEgIbDfD_BwE#overfitting) via early stopping, and will not be used to train the model. The evaluation set is often referred as [validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets) set.

On the other hand, [ML.EVALUATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-evaluate) function is used to evaluate model metrics using common metrics applicable to the type of model supplied. It's used to quantify the model's performance.

Answer (score 1):

ML.EVALUATE can be used to test the model against new data that wasn't available at the time the model was trained.

If you call ML.EVALUATE with just the model and without a table of data to evaluate, it will return the evaluation calculated during training.